# button onClick doesnt do anyhting NextJS using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

So i create a login page with a button to sign and hit API. but when i click the button, it doesn't do anything. is there any mistake in my code? i checked console log it didn't show any error or response.

how can i call the handleLogin function in a right way?

```
function LoginForm() {
  const { setAuth } = useContext<any>(AuthContext);
  const [showSnackbar, setShowSnackbar] = useState(false);
  const [field, setField] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
  

  function fieldHandler(e: any) {
    setField({
      ...field,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  async function handleLogin(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const loginReq = await axios.post(
        "https://spda-api.onrender.com/api/auth/login",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          },
          username: field.username,
          password: field.password,
        }
      );
      const loginResp = await loginReq.data;
      if (loginReq.status === 200) {
        setAuth(loginResp);
        Cookie.set("token", loginResp.token);
      
        Router.push("/admin/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as AxiosError;
      console.log(err);
      setShowSnackbar(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className="h-screen">
        <div className="container px-6 py-12 h-full">
          <div className=" md:w-8/12 lg:w-6/12 mb-12 md:mb-0">
            {showSnackbar && <SnackbarAlert message="Login gagal" />}
          </div>
                    <form>
//here is the input for username and password
                <div className="mb-6">
                                 <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={handleLogin}
                  className="inline-block px-7 py-3 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-sm leading-snug uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out w-full"
                  data-mdb-ripple="true"
                  data-mdb-ripple-color="light"
                >
                  Sign in
                </button>
              </form>
          
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

i think the way i call the function is wrong. anyone have a suggestion? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see here `type="button"`

```
           <button
              type="submit"                 
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
```

when type is set as `submit`, form data is sent to the form handler. since type is "button" there is no communication between form handler and button

Comment: even i didnt set onSubmit it still work with type submit?

Comment: your button has onClick. did it work?

Comment: i think my problem is some of my backend got cors, then i try to relogging and the button doesnt work. i think this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using TS, you should type the `e` parameter of `handleLogin`:

```
async function handleLogin(e: React.SyntheticEvent) { ... }
```

Then, add the `onSubmit` event to the `form` tag and make the `button` of type `submit`, removing its `onClick` event:

```
<form onSubmit="handleLogin">
  //here is the input for username and password
  <div className="mb-6">
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="inline-block px-7 py-3 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-sm leading-snug uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out w-full"
      data-mdb-ripple="true"
      data-mdb-ripple-color="light"
    >
      Sign in
    </button>
</form>
```